How to convert a string to a variable in universe basic?
For example, I want the result at last line of code print out as 1 but PARA2 is a string
EQU P.PARAMETER TO 1
PARA1="P."
PARA2=PARA1:"PARAMETER"
p=""
p<1>=2
PRINT PARA2
PRINT p<PARA2>


use associative arrays to store values and then access them using keys
`p = ""
p<"P.PARAMETER"> = 1
PARA1 = "P."
PARA2 = PARA1 : "PARAMETER"
PRINT p  ;* This will print "1"`

tested, the approach not working. Error pop out as non-numeric when numeric data required. Zero used. Furthermore, I have many include file like EQU A.PARAMETER TO 1,EQU B.PARAMETER TO 10 and etc. Even your approach work, I cannot change to the way you suggest as it going to break other application

you can’t dynamically reference variables using string concatenation

yeah i know that the rule that why wanted to find out any work around to do that.

what about using named fields in dynamic arrays:
`* Create a dynamic array with values in specific positions
p = ""          ;* Initialize a dynamic array
p<1> = 1        ;* Assign value to field 1 in array

Use a numeric index instead of a string-based reference
index = 1       ;* Define the index dynamically if needed
PRINT p  ;* This should print "1" without error`


Can you explain your use case? Is this for developer easy reading, or are these values being provided from the outside?
